# how to use async functions in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, asynchronous, async-await, future

I'm trying to return a boolean variable `res` using this function. The problem is it seems like the return is being done before the database access ended (the function runs fine because the prints works but the result of `res` when the function ends is always "false"). I am new at Flutter and I don't know how to resolve this.

```
bool es_fav(String id_producto) {
    // compruebo si el producto esta en la lista de favoritos o no
    final User? usuario = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    bool res = false;
    firestoreInstance
        .collection("Usuario")
        .where("email", isEqualTo: usuario!.email)
        .get()
        .then((value) {
      value.docs.forEach(
        (result) {
          print(result.get('productos_fav').toString());
          if (result.get('productos_fav').toString() == '[]') {
            print(
                "LA LISTA ESTÁ VACÍA. EL PRODUCTO NO ESTÁ EN LA LISTA DE FAVORITOS.\n");
            res == false;
          } else {
            while (res == false) {
              result.get('productos_fav').forEach((r) {
                if (r.toString() == id_producto) {
                  print("EL PRODUCTO ESTÁ EN LA LISTA DE FAVORITOS.\n");
                  res = true;
                }
              });
            }
          }
        },
      );
    });
    return res;
  }
```

EDIT:
My function is this right now:

```
Future<bool> es_fav(String id_producto) async {
final User? usuario = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
bool res = false;
final value = await firestoreInstance
    .collection("Usuario")
    .where("email", isEqualTo: usuario!.email)
    .get();
value.docs.forEach(
  (result) {
    print(result.get('productos_fav').toString());
    if (result.get('productos_fav').toString() == '[]') {
      print(
          "LA LISTA ESTÁ VACÍA. EL PRODUCTO NO ESTÁ EN LA LISTA DE FAVORITOS.\n");
      res == false;
    } else {
      while (res == false) {
        result.get('productos_fav').forEach((r) {
          if (r.toString() == id_producto) {
            print("EL PRODUCTO ESTÁ EN LA LISTA DE FAVORITOS.\n");
            res = true;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  },
);
return res;
```

}

but I have found a new problem. I need a "bool" return, not a "Future <bool" return because I am using this param for this widget:

```
Expanded(
                    child: Column(children: [
                      FavoriteButton(
                        isFavorite: es_fav(snapshot.data!.docs[index].id).then((value) => ??idk??? ),
                        iconSize: 30.0,
                        valueChanged: (_isFavorite) {
                          print('Is Favorite : $_isFavorite');
                          _modificar_producto_fav(context);
                        },
                      )
                    ]),
                  ),
```

I tried using .then() as you can see at the code above but it doesn't work

Comment: Your English is just fine as long as you don't write in shorthand abbreviations.

Comment: You need to make async the function 'as_fav' and await the "await firestoreInstance.collection("Usuario").where("email", isEqualTo: usuario!.email)......"

Comment: These two short videos about asynchronous programming in Dart: [Futures](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc) & [Async/Await](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OTS-ap9_aXc) will help you understand how to construct async code in Flutter/Dart.

Answer (score 0):

Your return statement is not inside of `then` nor is waiting for it to resolve, therefore it's returning from function before resolving `then`.
You should await for your async method to finish and only then return from function in order for it to resolve sequentially, something like this:

```
Future<bool> es_fav(String id_producto) async {
    final User? usuario = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    final firestoreInstance = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
    bool res = false;
    final value = await firestoreInstance
        .collection("Usuario")
        .where("email", isEqualTo: usuario!.email)
        .get();
    value.docs.forEach(
      (result) {
        print(result.get('productos_fav').toString());
        if (result.get('productos_fav').toString() == '[]') {
          print(
              "LA LISTA ESTÁ VACÍA. EL PRODUCTO NO ESTÁ EN LA LISTA DE FAVORITOS.\n");
          res == false;
        } else {
          while (res == false) {
            result.get('productos_fav').forEach((r) {
              if (r.toString() == id_producto) {
                print("EL PRODUCTO ESTÁ EN LA LISTA DE FAVORITOS.\n");
                res = true;
              }
            });
          }
        }
      },
    );
    return res;
  }
```

Now you can use the value of this function in your build method using FutureBuilder like this:

```
Expanded(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              FutureBuilder(
                future: es_fav('id_producto'),
                builder: (context, snap) {
                  FavoriteButton(
                    isFavorite: snap.data,
                    iconSize: 30.0,
                    valueChanged: (_isFavorite) {
                      print('Is Favorite : $_isFavorite');
                      _modificar_producto_fav(context);
                    },
                  );
                },
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )
```

Comment: Why should the OP ___try this___? **Good answers** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done that way,
not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO that may find this question and be reading your answer. If it is well answered maybe they will UpVote it.

Comment: Ok, thanks for pointing it out, I wrote my answer in hurry because I have to go now. I'll edit it with some explanation to be more useful.

Comment: Hi! Thank you so much!! It works but I found a new problem: The return of this function ("is_fav") is used for a bool parameter of a widget, so I need a "bool" return, not a Future<bool> return (I'm going to copy the rest of the code below on the original question-post because I can't copy that in this comment).

Comment: I updated my solution according to your updated question, it should be complete solution to your question now.